# Is it possible to use Single Sends without click tracking?

Tags: sendgrid-api-v3

I'm using SendGrid's [Single Sends](https://docs.sendgrid.com/api-reference/single-sends/create-single-send) in order to send mail to a contact list with unsubscribes, and I have both Open Tracking and Click Tracking disabled in the [Tracking Settings](https://app.sendgrid.com/settings/tracking). Despite this, all of the links in my emails are still converted to `https://u....ct.sendgrid.net/ls/click?...` tracking links.

Is there a way to disable this click tracking?

Comment: Are you sending HTML-emails or plaintext emails? Or both?

Comment: I'm setting both `html_content` and `plain_content`, and I'd like it to leave my HTML alone.